# How can I load Dired+ only if I actually use Dired?

Tags: dired, use-package

I'm loading dired+ from a file ( as it has been removed from Melpa ), but it won't load when I try to make it conditional of opening a dired buffer.

```
;; ---- Dired + --------
;; Loads Dired+ 

(use-package dired+
  :load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa-offline/dired+"   

  :after dired
  
  :config
  (require 'dired+)
  (print "Dired + package Loaded")
)
```

Also I tried making it depending of using a binding key but it doesn't load that way either:

```
;; ---- Dired + --------
;; Loads Dired+ Manually

(use-package dired+
  :load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa-offline/dired+"   

  :bind ( "C-x d" . dired)
  
  :config
  (require 'dired+)
  (print "Dired + package Loaded")
)
```

The `(print "Dired + package Loaded")` is just so I can check if is properly loading on the message buffer.

Comment: Is the question only how to do it with `use-package`? If not, *just use `dired-load-hook`.* (Presumably you don't want to reload Dired+ each time you open a Dired buffer or reread a Dired listing.)

Comment: I'm trying to make the Emacs loading time shorter, and Dired+ takes almost two seconds of the six or seven seconds that takes Emacs to be ready for typing. The idea was to avoid loading Dired+ until I open a dired buffer with `("C-x d")`.

Comment: I just tried using `dired-load-hook` but it doesn't make a difference because Emacs seems to load dired when starts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use one of the hooks (`dired-before-readin-hook` or `dired-mode-hook`) that's used each time Dired is used, but have your hook function do just `(require 'dired+)`, so it does nothing once Dired+ has been loaded.

I would probably put it on **`dired-before-readin-hook`**. Use `M-x customize-variable` and add this hook function:

```lisp
(defun my-require-dired+ ()
  "Require Dired+."
  (require 'dired+))

(add-hook 'dired-before-readin-hook 'my-require-dired+)
```

Comment: Awesome!. It works perfectly. It even works with tramp when I open a remote folder.